# how to choose thread pool(s)?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

for example, I have an application with 3 layers:

```
HTTP Layer -> App Logic -> Db Layer
```

every layer uses a thread pool.

Should I use one thread pool for handling?

Or the best way to process is to use different pools per different layers. Because I know that some queries to DB-Layer are complex and heavy, and I prefer to use a separate layer for DB logic.

And how to select thread pools size in such cases? Should I relay to processor count? Because if I use 3 thread pools, they should bother each other. Or I wrong in my assumptions?

Comment: 1. *Should I use one thread pool for handling?*, you mean on each layer? 2. Are all layers on the same computer? 3. The question may fit better in [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) because it is more about architecture than implementation, if I get you right.

Comment: 1. yep, on each layer. 
2. yep, it's the same computer.
3. ok, I will ask there

Answer (score 0):

First thing is know that threading not tightly coupled with any specific layer, it's depends on the usage of specific problem statement.

You can also use only ONE thread for all the layers, and invoke methods/functions defined in other layers.  The drawback of use many thread is that it could cause deadlock, and dealing with them is not quite easy. So try to minimise creating more threads. The reason being creating thread and managing them is not easy underhood.

When it comes to thread pools size - It shouldn't be less or high in numbers, the basic ideas is to utilise the resource to perform actions.  Ideally `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` use to get number of processors.